# jquery DOM manipulation - more efficient way of doing this

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-mobile, append

I am doing a a lot of repeating segments of code for a mobile html app.  To asve download time, I have been trying to reduce html code and automate with jQuery, but jquery is getting quite verbose.  Here is example.  Can this type of thing be made less verbose and more efficient?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">

tplCnf = "\n\n\
        <center>\n\
        <div data-role='content' data-theme='b'>\n\
                <fieldset data-role='controlgroup' data-type='horizontal'>\n\
                    <input type='radio' name='FMT' id='' value='S' checked='checked' /><label   name='FMT' for=''>Serial</label>\n\
                    <input type='radio' name='FMT' id='' value='P' /><label                     name='FMT' for=''>Parallel</label>\n\
                    <input type='radio' name='FMT' id='' value='O' /><label                     name='FMT' for=''>Other</label>\n\
                </fieldset>\n\
        </div>\n\
        </center>";

$(document).ready(function()
{
    /* This is used to populate configuration types */          
    var groups = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'];

    /* add data config type types */
        for (var myLetters in groups){
            // clone fragment of html
            myTmpl = $(tplCnf); 

            // create a unique name for Configuratin radio boxes and corresponding labels
            myTmpl.find('input[name="FMT"]')                
                .attr("name", "FMT-"+groups[myLetters]);                
            myTmpl.find('label[name="FMT"]')                
                .attr("name", "FMT-"+groups[myLetters]);

            // apply id name to first configuration radio box 
            name1 = "preConfigRadio-" + groups[myLetters] + "1";            
            myTmpl.find('input[name="FMT-"+ groups[myLetters]]:eq(0)')
                .attr("id", name1)
            myTmpl.find('label[name="FMT-"+ groups[myLetters]]:eq(0)')
                .attr("for", name1);

            // apply id name to second configuration radio box 
            name2 = "preConfigRadio-" + groups[myLetters] + "2";            
            myTmpl.find('input[name="FMT-"+ groups[myLetters]]:eq(1)')
                .attr("id", name2);
            myTmpl.find('label[name="FMT-"+ groups[myLetters]]:eq(1)')
                .attr("for", name2);

            // apply id name to third configuration radio box 
            name3 = "preConfigRadio-" + groups[myLetters] + "3";
            myTmpl.find('input[name="FMT-"+ groups[myLetters]]:eq(2)')
                .attr("id", name3);
            myTmpl.find('label[name="FMT-"+ groups[myLetters]]:eq(2)')
                .attr("for", name3);

            // then append
            myTmpl.appendTo("#placeholder"+groups[myLetters]).trigger('create');                                    
        }
});

</script>   

</head> 
<body>  

<!-- ***   Navigation bar   *** -->
<div data-role="page"  id="preHelpTab">
<div data-role="header" data-position="inline">

<input type="hidden" id="preBeginRequestDtls" name="BeginRequestDtls" value=""  />

        <div id='groupA' class='preGroups'> 
        This is Group A
            <div id='placeholderA' ></div>  

        </div>

        <div id='groupB' class='preGroups'> 
        This is Group B
            <div id='placeholderB' ></div>  
        </div>

        <div id='groupC' class='preGroups'> 
        This is Group C
            <div id='placeholderC' ></div>  
        </div>

        <div id='groupD' class='preGroups'> 
        This is Group D
            <div id='placeholderD' ></div>  
        </div>

        <div id='groupE' class='preGroups'> 
        This is Group E
            <div id='placeholderE' ></div>  
        </div>

        <div id='groupF' class='preGroups'> 
        This is Group F
            <div id='placeholderF' ></div>  
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing some quotation marks here and there, I doubt .find('input[name="FMT-"+ groups[myLetters]]:eq(0)') is working as intended

Comment: just re-tested.  does it fail for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic looks good but you can improvise on the performance of the code by caching the local variables instead of finding them multiple times. Take a look at this

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    /* This is used to populate configuration types */          
    var groups = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'], inputs, label, name;

    /* add data config type types */
        for (var myLetters in groups){
            // clone fragment of html
            myTmpl = $(tplCnf); 

            // create a unique name for Configuratin radio boxes and corresponding labels
            inputs = myTmpl.find('input[name="FMT"]')                
                .attr("name", "FMT-"+groups[myLetters]);                
            lables = myTmpl.find('label[name="FMT"]')                
                .attr("name", "FMT-"+groups[myLetters]);

            for(var i =0;i<3;i++){
               name = "preConfigRadio-" + groups[myLetters] + (i+1);            
               inputs.eq(i).attr("id", name)
               labels.eq(i).attr("for", name);
            }

            // then append
            myTmpl.appendTo("#placeholder"+groups[myLetters]).trigger('create');                                    
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/)

Create a single input element template like this:

```
<script id="inputTemplate" type="text/html">
    <input type='radio' name="${groupName}" id="${id}" value="${value}" />
    <label name="${labelName}" for="${for}">${labelValue}</label>
</script>
```

Then you can create a template for group of inputs like this:

```
<script id="groupTemplate" type="text/html">
    <center>
        <div data-role='content' data-theme='b'>
            <fieldset data-role='controlgroup' data-type='horizontal'>
                ${inputItem}
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </center>
</script>
```

Now, using both of these, the actual jQuery code will become a lot more manageable!!

Define your DataSet for inputs:

```
var inputDataSet = [
    { groupName: "FMT-A", id: 1, value: "", labelName: "1A", for: "", labelValue: "123" },
    { groupName: "FMT-A", id: 2, value: "", labelName: "2A", for: "", labelValue: "123123" },
    { groupName: "FMT-A", id: 3, value: "", labelName: "3A", for: "", labelValue: "1231231" }
]
```

Finally one single line to cast and append:

```
$("#groupTemplate").tmpl($("#inputTemplate").tmpl(inputDataSet)).appendTo("#placeholder");
```

I know the actual values and logic you have is not matched perfectly but essentially this is how you should do this kind of thing. jQuery Templates allow you much better code manageability and cleaner DOM manipulation for situations like this when you want to insert variable data based HTML elements to the page.

Also, these are used extensively with AJAX calls, because you can display POST result data effortlessly.

Comment: great idea, but being a mobile app, I want to try avoid adding additional code if possible.

Comment: Fair enough, it is still seriously worth considering since the minified file is 4.8Kb which will cache on most mobile browsers today. I am presuming that you need this on multiple pages in which case it is definitely the way to go.